# How to use ChartJS outside a module?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to use chart.js in plain JavaScript like

```html
<html>
<body>
<DIV>my contents</div>
<script src="/static/defapp/js/chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(My environment is in aws isolated subnet so can not access to the internet, so, I can not use `CDN`)

above code shows the error like this

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at chart.min.js:1:1)

Then I checked this [article](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html).

It uses the `chart.umd.js` however I can't find the `chart.umd.js` in [GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js).

Where can I find this?

Comment: Can you download the script from the CDN to use locally?  I guess it's not clear to me how you're getting the library in the first place if downloading it from the internet isn't an option.

Comment: @David i opend the js file on CDN and save by browser.

Comment: Download the chart.js-<version>.tgz from GitHub. Extract the files to a folder. Inside the package\dist folder there is a chart.umd.js file, along with a chart.umd.js.map file.

Comment: Modules _are_ "plain JavaScript".

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you I can find the chart.umd.js and it works!

Answer (score 3):

**Use Chart.js with a CDN:**

Instead of including the Chart.js library via a local file path, try using a Content Delivery Network (CDN) link to include the library. This approach can sometimes help avoid issues related to module syntax.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

**Check Chart.js Version Compatibility:**
Ensure that the version of Chart.js you're using is compatible with plain JavaScript usage. Older versions of Chart.js may not fully support this usage pattern.

**Wrap Chart.js Code in a Function:**
Wrap your Chart.js code inside a function and call that function after the document has loaded. This ensures that the Chart.js library is fully loaded before attempting to use it.

```
<script>
  function createChart() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
  }
  window.onload = createChart;
</script>
```

**Use Chart.js Module Version:**

Consider using the module version of Chart.js if your project supports ES6 modules. This version is designed to work with modern JavaScript module syntax.

```
<script type="module">
  import Chart from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js';
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
</script>
```

**Check Browser Compatibility:**

Ensure that the browser you're using supports the JavaScript features used by Chart.js. Some older browsers may not fully support modern JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
However in my environment is in aws isolated subnet, so I can't use CDN.

Comment: and I tested the script lijke this,

`<script type="module">
    import Chart from '/js/chart.min.js';
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
</script>`

However it shows the error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: This issue often happens when working with JavaScript modules (ES6 modules), and it indicates that a required dependency is not being handled properly. To fix this, make sure all the necessary dependencies for Chart.js are included in your project. If the problem persists, you might consider using a tool like Webpack to manage the module resolution process.